# Why isn't "!duplicateNote.length" working?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, ecmascript-6

I'm using yargs to create a note taking app accessed via the command line. When I enter a new title, it's supposed to check and make sure a title like the one entered doesn't already exist to avoid duplicates. So if there isn't a duplicate, theoretically it should evaluate to `!duplicateNote.length` because there's nothing inside.

However, the undefined object is causing my application to break, where it was once working. And I can't figure it out. Everything has been required correctly.

**APP.JS FILE**

```js
yargs.command({
    command: 'add',
    describe: 'Add a new note',
    builder: {
        title: {
            describe: 'Note title',
            demandOption: true,
            type: 'string'
        }, 
        body: {
            describe: 'Note body',
            demandOption: true,
            type: 'string'
        }
    },
    handler(argv) {
        notes.addNote(argv.title, argv.body)
    }
})
```

**NOTES.JS FILE**

```js
const addNote = (title, body) => {
    const notes = loadNotes()
    const duplicateNote = notes.find((note) => note.title === title)

    if (!duplicateNote.length) {
        notes.push({
            title: title,
            body: body
        })
        saveNotes(notes)
        console.log(chalk.green.inverse('New note added!'))
    } else {
        console.log(chalk.bgRed('Note title taken!'))
    }
}

const loadNotes= () => {
    try {
        const dataBuffer = fs.readFileSync('notes.json')
        const dataJSON = dataBuffer.toString()
        return JSON.parse(dataJSON)
    } catch (e) {
        return[]
    }

}

module.exports = {
    addNote:    addNote,
    removeNote: removeNote,
    listNotes:  listNotes,
    readNote:   readNote
}
```

I expect "New note added!" to be logged to the console, but instead, I get:`TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: What do you expect `duplicateNote` to be? Please check what [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because if there's nothing to `find`, you get `undefined`. Use `filter` if you want to check that.

```
const duplicateNote = notes.filter((note) => note.title === title)
```

`filter` always gives an array - `find` gives either `undefined`, or whatever data type is found.

Comment: OMG, thank you. I stared at that waaaaaay too long for such an obvious error.

Comment: No problem @Michael, always glad to help. If my answer fixed your problem please accept it.